# GVRSDK iOS Xcode linker error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a GVRCardboardView in my iOS app written in Xcode 8.2, Swift 3.0. I have a GVRVideoView running but can't get the app to compile when adding with the GVRCardboardView. I am using a Bridging-Header to gain access to the Objective C files for the the cardboard SDK.

This is the header file:

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h

#import "GVRWidgetView.h"
#import "GVRPanoramaView.h"
#import "GVROverlayView.h"
#import "GVRVideoView.h"
#import "GVRHeadTransform.h"
#import "GVRCardboardView.h"
#import "GVRAudioEngine.h"

#endif
```

And the resulting error when compiling...

```
ld: library not found for -lGVRView_arm
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I change my Podfile from: (reference @ https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk/blob/master/Samples/TreasureHunt/Podfile)

```
target 'My App Name' do
    pod 'GVRSDK/SDK'
end
```

to:

```
target 'My App Name' do
    pod 'GVRSDK'
end
```

Then the resulting error changes to:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GVRCardboardView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MyGVRViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It seems now the app can find the -lGVRView_arm code but now isn't properly linking to the GVRCardboardView objective C class.

What am I missing? Why won't my app compile?

--EDIT--

As the error stated that there is an undefined symbol for architecture **armv7**, I tried a newer device with **arm64**. I still receive a similar error.

Comment: I had to add the 'use_frameworks' to make this work I believe

Comment: Just added 'use_frameworks!' to the Podfile. no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to one of the collaborators on the project, this is a bug in the latest release of the GVRSDK (ver 1.10.0) https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk/issues/189

The issue arises when attempting to use some form of GVRVideoView (or other GVRView) class AND a GVRCardboardView in the same project. In the latest release, these classes are separated out into different .a files: libGVRSDK_arm.a and libGVRView_arm.a. Attempting to download and use both of them at the same time will result in duplicate file errors.

To fix this issue, use the previous version of the CocoaPod with the following Podfile and wait for an update...

```
target 'My App Name' do
    pod 'GVRSDK', '1.0.1'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `pod 'CardboardSDK'` into your pod file and do `pod install` and then import following into your bridging header

```
#import "GCSCardboardView.h"
#import "GCSCardboardAudioEngine.h"
#import "GCSHeadTransform.h"
#import "GCSWidgetView.h"
#import "GCSPanoramaView.h"
#import "GCSVideoView.h"
```

Make sure you remove `pod 'GVRSDK'` from your pod file. This method worked for me on Xcode 8.2.1 Swift 3.0.2

Comment: Looks like this does work, but it is just reverting back to a previous version of the CocoaPod. Instead of going back 7 versions to v0.7.1, I was able to go back one version to v1.0.1 with the following: `pod 'GVRSDK', '1.0.1'`

Comment: Oh, then I'll also move to 1.0.1 instead of 0.7.1